# How to use variable/user_func in a conditional statement in Typoscript (TYPO3 6.2)?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I want to use a conditional statement for applying a different template to News (tt_news). Currently I use a user function that returns true/false. If the current News has a specific category and works correctly return `1` otherwise return `Null`.

I followed the official documentation and other sites, so I made the condition

```
[userFunc = user_isLatin]
 plugin.tt_news.templateFile = fileadmin/templates/plugins/tt_news/latin_detail.html
 page.1010 = TEXT
 page.1010.value = LATIN  
[ELSE]
 plugin.tt_news.templateFile = fileadmin/templates/plugins/tt_news/general_detail.html
 page.1010 = TEXT
 page.1010.value = OTHERS      
[END]
```

but it always shows `OTHERS`. I tried the following with variables

```
temp.catuid = USER
temp.catuid.preUserFunc = user_ttNewsInCat

latin = TEXT
latin.value < temp.catuid

[latin.value = 1]
 ....
[ELSE]
 ....
[END]
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No for this way. I had to find another way for resolve this, through programming in frontend using markers and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly like you tried to do it.
This is the cobndition I tested now:

```
[userFunc = user_isLatin]
 page.10 = TEXT
 page.10.value = LATIN
[ELSE]
 page.10 = TEXT
 page.10.value = OTHERS      
[END]
```

And this is the implementation of the user function which must be in the AdditionalConfiguration.php or the localcon.php file of your custom extension (I suppose this is what you missed).

```
function user_isLatin() {
    return TRUE;
}
```

For more details see the offcial documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#userfunc

Comment: I tried your propose but Typoscript condition did not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `user_` function in 6.2, you can also use a class.
And you don't need to define it in AdditionalConfiguration.php.

TypoScript:

```
[userFunc = Vendor\ExtName\Condition\TypoScriptCondition::isLatin()]
...
[else]
...
[global]
```

PHP:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtName\Condition;

class TypoScriptCondition
{

    public static function isLatin()
    {
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works probably, but it is stil an undocumented feature in 6.2. At least not in this specific scope. True is that in the global scope in all user function use cases namespaces can be used to resolve a user function which is stil a usefull information.

Comment: I did a Pull Request to add this to the documentation of 6.2 and will add it to 7.6, too: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Conditions/Reference/#userfunc